# Having problems understanding Props - can someone explain what prop is . being passed?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am trying to understand the props being passed in the code below... What is the props being passed through the constructor attributed too? Is it value?

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <NameForm />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Props get passed into the component from a parent. For example: `<NameForm exampleProp="example value" anotherProp={ { someObjectProp: "a value in an object" } }> children prop goes here </NameForm>` can then be accessed as props.exampleProp and props.anotherProp and props.children

Answer (score 0):

Props are just a way to pass objects - variables or functions etc, into a component for that component to use.

Think of it like this - you want to use this component in multiple places so it would help to pass in the initial data the form would need, rather than have the form need to have to fetch the data itself. This keeps it encapsulated and reusable.

So when using this component, you could pass in the user data needed to render in the form as prop:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <NameForm user={user} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

In your component, you could then use the prop however you need. As an example:

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {user: props.user};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  ...

<input type="text" value={this.state.user.name}
```

Answer (score 0):

**“Props”** is a special keyword in React, which stands for properties and is being used for passing data from one component to another.
For an instance, when you are loading a component inside another component then let say you need some data to show that component. Then in this point of time you have to pass a prop to that component and further the component would collect that prop in the constructor.

> Example :-

In the present scenario you have list of hotels and clicking on a hotel will redirect to hotel descricption screen then before loading hotel description screen you need the hotel id so that you can get the descrition of that hotel. So you have to pass a prop when loading a component and that passed prop will be fetched inside the constructor

access props inside component, if you pass props name as text

```
{props.text}
```

references :- [you can see here in detail](https://itnext.io/what-is-props-and-how-to-use-it-in-react-da307f500da0)